# How to group by last week in linq

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, linq, lambda

I have a picturelikes table in my database. For every like a new picture like table row will be created. I want to group those likes by lastweek and pictureid, meaning all the likes for one single pic in the last week should be accumulated and become one like.Then i will be able to sort them by thier count.

This is my picturelike table :

```
public partial class picturelike
{
    public int idpicturelike { get; set; }
    public int idpictures { get; set; }
    public int iduser { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime iddatetime { get; set; }
    public int iduserlikedby { get; set; }
    public int likenumber { get; set; }
}
```

Till now i am able to write this code, this is my web api controller code  using linq.

```
  var combo = from p in db.picturelikes
                    group p by new {p.iddatetime, p.idpictures } into pgroup
                    let count = pgroup.Count()
                    orderby count descending
                    select new SortedDto
                    {
                        IdPictures=pgroup.FirstOrDefault().idpictures,
                        IdPictureLike = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().idpicturelike,
                        IdUser = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().iduser,
                        IdDatetime = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().iddatetime,
                        IdUserLikedBy = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().iduserlikedby,
                        LikeNumber = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().likenumber
                    };

        return combo;
```

So what else i need to do, how to make this code working, i am stuck here, how should i do it?

Comment: What is the error, result, defect you observed? How did it fail?

Comment: Lastweek, as in over the last 7 days?

Comment: Gusdor, its not failiing its just grouping by matching dates  which i dont want, i want to group it by the last 7 days

Comment: If answers are not fixing the problem you are describing, then your question is junk. Consider revising.

Comment: I'm not understanding it quitly. `group on the last 7 days`, do you mean `group on each day` with  `only for the last 7 days`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot group by the last seven days. You have to filter first (`where`), then group:

```
var pastDate= DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7);    
var combo = from p in db.picturelikes
                    where p.iddatetime.Date > pastDate
                    group p by p.iddatetime.Date into pgroup
                    let count = pgroup.Count()
                    orderby count descending
                    select new SortedDto
                    {
                        IdPictures=pgroup.FirstOrDefault().idpictures,
                        IdPictureLike = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().idpicturelike,
                        IdUser = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().iduser,
                        IdDatetime = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().iddatetime,
                        IdUserLikedBy = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().iduserlikedby,
                        LikeNumber = pgroup.FirstOrDefault().likenumber
                    };

        return combo;
```

An explaination of this line:

```
where p.iddatetime.Date > DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7)
```

The Date property is **just** the date component of the time. We snap to midnight and filter by the logical days of the week, not by hours. This will give you more palatable results but feel free to change it.

Comment: Gusdor its not the problem, its doing what it is supposed to do. I  just want the added functionality in this line that it should be able to gropuby last week.

Comment: Gusdor can you explain this line                     where p.iddatetime.Date > DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-1)

Comment: @Hmmmmmmmmmm the -1 was a typo (should have been -7). I've fixed it and put in some comments.

Comment: I am getting this error "The specified type member 'Date' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.",

Comment: LINQ-to-Entities can deal with local values but not local expressions. Your code will work with this minor change:  var pastDate= DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7); and making where like this :        where p.iddatetime > pastDate

Comment: @Hmmmmmmmmmm try assigning both dates using a let clause. If that doesnt work, remove .Date. It is optional.

Comment: Make changes in your code so that i can accept it is as a right answer :)

Comment: Your code will work with this minor change: var pastDate= DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7); and making where like this : where p.iddatetime > pastDate  make changes

Answer (score 0):

To select only the rows from the last week, you can add a `where` clause to your linq statement, e.g.

```
where p.iddatetime > (DateTime.Today - TimeSpan.FromDays(7))
```

Comment: where p.iddatetime.Date >= DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(-7).Date

Comment: I am getting this error LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan FromDays(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.",